# Double precision in 64 vs 32 bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, stochastic

I'm wondering if Excel VBA stores doubles with different levels of precision in 32 vs 64 bit editions of the product.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm looking at a stochastic model, and I've noted that I'm getting very small differences in output using seeded random numbers (difference would be implied by a difference in a trigger threshold in roughly 1 in 200M numbers).

The code based is identical, so I wasn't sure if there's additional precision in 64 which might be causing a delta in probability threshold conditions with a vanishingly small level of occurrence vs the run in 32.

Looking at the VBA documentation, I couldn't see any specific call outs on precision, but I'm aware that with that documentation, just because something is written down doesn't mean there isn't something there!

Comment: Is it not a case of the seeding in 64 vs 32 rather than the storage of a double?

Comment: I'd suggest to read this: [Compatibility between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office). VBA7 enables you to run macro with 2 conditional compilations. Using `Win64` directive you can "force" your code to run in 64bit mode. More at: [64-bit Visual Basic for Applications overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview). I doubt that result may differ in 32/64 bit environment.

Answer (score 2):

No - excel uses the same precision for doubles in both 32 and 64 bit Excel.